# @parcel/optimizer-css: missing field `analyzeDependencies`

Tags: parceljs, parcel

Action on gitHub pages.
When I tried to push app with this object

```
const iconCatalog = {
  200: require('../image/animated/503-522-314-200-230d-rainy-day.svg'),
};
export default iconCatalog;
```

I have an error
*@parcel/optimizer-css: missing field **analyzeDependencies***

[image]

If I change this object

```
 const iconCatalog = {
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KsanaSal/weather-project-shecodes/main/src/image/animated/201-211-221d-thunderstorms-day.svg',
    };
 export default iconCatalog;
```

App deployed without any issues

this is my deploy.yml

```
name: Build and deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1

      - name: Install and Build 
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.0
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: dist
```

That is mean? I can't find solution on this. How and where I can add this missing field?